# How can I enlarge the box under the Stack Exchange dropdown?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

On the top left, there is the Stack Exchange button, which opens a list box with all the communities I am a member of, and then all communities that exist.
I'd like to enlarge the standard box size, so I can see all my communities at once, but it seems fixed (to show about 8½ lines only).

Is there a way to configure it to come up larger? If not, consider this a feature request…

Answer (score 4):

A custom user-stylesheet will help. Find those lines in `all.css`:

```
.topbar-dialog.siteSwitcher-dialog {
    width: 375px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 390px; //<-- edit this!
    max-height: 390px; //<-- edit this!
}
```

And the rules in the user-stylesheet to change min and max height.

You'll get something like this with both set to 700px:

> [image]

Comment: I managed to do that live in Chrome, but how do I make the site always use my version of all.css in the future? I am not too familiar with web programming

Comment: @Aganju http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm. It's typically a browser extension. I have been able to find https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en for Chrome.

Comment: I think installing an extension is a bit overkill, and Chrome does not have native support for custom CSS anymore. Also, the changed CSS would apply to all pages, not just this one, right? - I am not able to use extension anyway, as they are blocked in my company, but that is specific to me.